# What is the correct way to notify a SwiftUI parent/host View of the end a Class URLSession task?

Tags: asynchronous, swiftui, combine

**Scenario:** An asynchronous session is used within a **Class** to access an off-line server. 
There are several **endpoints** that are accessed via a **class enum** per context of the request from the container view. 
The data accumulates in a **Singleton class** amongst other endpoints for quicker access via member views.

One member view is displayed per endpoint.

**Goal:** to *notify the parent View* after the requested endpoint has returned data for display; which in turn populates a particular member view.

**Problem:** Needless to say, the member view is always rendered ***before*** receiving the data. 
That is, it's out-of-sync.

In fact, the only way to have the data seen is via a button on the container view to display the member view with the data on demand.  This is NOT what I want. I want this to happen automatically upon data-source selection.

**My Solution:** to fire off a **Notification** *to the container view* once data is available so the container view can render the appropriate member view with the data.

**Problem:** I'm using the **publisher-subscribe** scenario to wait for notification so I can display the data.  
But I'm confused at handling the subscriber within the container view.

I was thinking of using the **NSNotification** use of a handler @Objc function vs publish/subscribe. 
 
But I'm mixing imperative with the subjective paradigm here.

The following piece of code posts the notification upon receiving data:

```
   case .AppleCountryProvince:
        let url = URL(string: "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/apple/countries/Canada")!
        let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map(\.data)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .decode(type: DMAppleSubRegion.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .print("AppleSubRegion: ")

        remoteDataPublisher
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    print("Publisher Finished")
                case let .failure(anError):
                    Swift.print("\nReceived error: ", anError)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { someValue in
                SingletonData.shared.appleSubRegion = someValue
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: noteName, object: DataModelType.AppleCountryProvince)
            }).store(in: &cancellables)
```

The following code snippet is within a function of a View to handle the Notification.  
 This isn't firing.

```
    _ = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: noteName)
        .sink { note in
            if let source = note.object as? DataSource.DataModelType {
                switch source {
                case .AppleCountries:
                    print("AppleCountries")
                case .AppleCountryProvince:
                    print("AppleCountryProvince")
                case .AppleSubRegions:
                    print("AppleSubRegions")
                case .ILINET:
                    print("ILINET")
                case .CDC:
                    print("CDC")
                case .PHL:
                    print("PHL")

                default:
                    print("Default")
                }
            }
        }
```

**Question:** should I pass a publisher variable between the class & the container view from which to launch the subscriber?

I understand the cause/affect of using @State <--> @Binding in *synchronous* time.
But I need the have the view react *asynchronously* upon the conclusion of acquiring the server data.

I'm not sure I can use the conventional NSNotification within the container view.

**The bottom line:** can I get the container view to react to the end of the network session?

Comment: I'm not fully following your scenario, and not quite sure which one is "member view", a "container view", and "parent view".. but whatever view you want notified could use [`.onReceive(:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onreceive(_:perform:)) to listen to any publisher... alternatively, you could have an `@EnvironmentObject` or `@ObservedObject` that could be used to conditionally display things when something asynchronously occurs

Comment: Off-topic, but that an incorrect usage of the Singleton pattern